# How to Replace only a word in C# and not the specific letters in a word?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to replace some string as using .Replace in C#

i have a string contains words like

this is 1st answer this is 2nd answer this is 3rd answer this is 4th answer

now when i try to replace "is" from the above string

"this" also gets replaced and out comes 
th 1st answer th  2nd answer th  3rd answer th 4th answer

i only want to replace a specific word and not the half word

Kindly help

Comment: can't you just replace " is " with spaces for the word you want also with spaces in front and in the back?

Comment: @Paweł Łukasik thakyou that helped....working fine now